# Incorrect collision detection

Tags: python, pygame

I created a "character" object and a "block" group
I made it possible for the "character" object to move smoothly
I would like "character" not to overlap with "block" The current collision blocking works as follows: The "character" object may overlap with the "block" object, but if the key is released, "character" will exit the "block". I would like to fix it

```
# an object that can move
class Character():
    def __init__(self, screen, ai_settings):
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/character.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_right = False

    def update(self):
        if self.moving_up:
            self.rect.y -= self.ai_settings.CHARACTER_SPEED_FACTOR
        if self.moving_down:
            self.rect.y += self.ai_settings.CHARACTER_SPEED_FACTOR
        if self.moving_left:
            self.rect.x -= self.ai_settings.CHARACTER_SPEED_FACTOR
        if self.moving_right:
            self.rect.x += self.ai_settings.CHARACTER_SPEED_FACTOR

class Block(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/block.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```

Try block collision

```
def check_keydown_events(event, character, blocks):
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        #Start up smoothly moving up
        character.moving_up = True

        for block in blocks:
            if character.rect.colliderect(block.rect):
                character.rect.top = block.rect.bottom
        #Attempt to block a collision
```

Full code: https://github.com/Deweri/IncompleateMaze

Comment: What, specifically, is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you describe (`Character` sprite ends up overlapping `Block` before collision is detected), it looks like the problem is the stepped-movement of a `Character`.

Looking at the code:

```
class Character( ... ):

    def update(self):
        if self.moving_up:
            self.rect.y -= self.ai_settings.CHARACTER_SPEED_FACTOR
        ...
```

Movement is simply applying a delta of `self.ai_settings.CHARACTER_SPEED_FACTOR`, updating the screen, and *then* checking for collision.  This shows the `Character` temporarily overlapping the `Block`.

One way to fix this would be to check for collisions in `Character.update()`. So if, say moving *X* pixels up would result in a collision, only move the available amount of pixels, and set `self.moving_up = False`.